# Understanding the symbols next to the Ticker

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-exchanges, chart

I'm quite new to trading but am getting a decent handle on it, including reading charts. I came across this bit of information that's confusing me on the tradingview.com charts.

[image]

1. I don't understand what the `D`, to the right of `APPLE INC,` means.
2. I'm not understanding how it can say `BATS` when in actuality `AAPL` is listed on the `NASDAQ`. Do all exchanges have info on every stock even from other exchanges and just give them to end-users at a delayed rate?

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand what the D, to the right of APPLE INC, means.

This means the graph below is for the "D". There is selection at top and you can change this to Minutes [5,20,60,etc], Day, Week [W], Month [M]

> I'm not understanding how it can say BATS when in actuality AAPL is listed on the NASDAQ. Do all exchanges have info on every stock even from other exchanges and just give them to end-users at a delayed rate?

BATS is an exchange. A stock can be listed on multiple exchange. I am not sure if AAPL is also listed on BATS. However looks like BATS has agreement with major stock exchanges to trade their data and [supplies this to trading.com](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro/#markets)

Answer (score 1):

BATS here means your data feed is coming from BATS only. You're not seeing up to date prices from NASDAQ, NYSE or any other of the ECNs. For a liquid equity like AAPL, BATS prices are typically up to date but for a less liquid listing, you wouldn't always see the NBBO.
To get live feeds from every ECN, you have to pay. BATS is offering this information freely and that's why you're seeing it now.
AAPL is listed on NASDAQ but you can trade pretty much everything on BATS, just like on other ECNs and exchanges.